# No internet through VPN server

Tags: vpn, configuration, vps

Recently I've posted almost the same thread on this forum about VPN misconfiguration. Eventually, I've resolved this question just by reconfiguring from scratch the server side, and it started to work properly. But the one thing that I've faced is - I don't have internet access connecting through my VPN server.  I've used the trace route command to detect where traffic stops, and obviously it stops at my VPN server. I really don't know how to deal with it. Anyone help me please:) Here's my Server config and Client config. And yes my VPN server uses Debian 8.0  and from client side it's Windows 7 and 10.

Server config.

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh dh2048.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
```

Client config. Note: Server's IP is hidden.

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote 107.155.1x4.1x2 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca "C:\\OVPN\\ca.crt"
cert "C:\\OVPN\\client1.crt"
key "C:\\OVPN\\client1.key"
ns-cert-type server
comp-lzo
verb 3
```

Any suggestions would be really helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
```

> Pushing the redirect-gateway option to clients will cause all IP network traffic originating on client machines to pass through the OpenVPN server. **The server will need to be configured to deal with this traffic somehow**, such as by NATing it to the internet, or routing it through the server site's HTTP proxy.

After this, on the server you will need to

- enable also ip_forward
- SNAT (or MASQUERADE) your VPN originated traffic using iptables or nftables

Comment: In one of the server's config I've already configured the following things:
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1    (in server.conf)

And then installed UFW firewall where I've configured it's config file:
DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="ACCEPT"    ( By default this policy is DROP.)

Comment: Then I've added additional UFW rules for network address translation and IP masquerading of connected clients. It's again ufw config "ufw/before.rules"

# START OPENVPN RULES
# NAT table rules
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
# Allow traffic from OpenVPN client to eth0
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# END OPENVPN RULES

Anyway it doesn't work, I used the VPN guide from DigitalOcean - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-debian-8
(sorry if I cannot post here external links)

Comment: also, please ping from the client an external ip (not a host!), like 8.8.8.8 (google's DNS server), and show the output of tcpdump -pni <interface> for the server's openvpn interface, and the interface you break out to the net

Comment: hey buddy, I've tested it like you told me. The ping to 8.8.8.8 from client machine doesn't work.

here's the tcpdumb output
tcpdump -pni tun0
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode listening on tun0, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 262144 bytes

So what we gonna do next? Can't figure out how to do it. Tried to use tcpdump -v tun0  - the output is "syntax error"

Comment: And the interface I break out to the net I use TAP on my Windows computer.

Comment: you need to confirm, that the packets are sent on the vpn channel (tcpdump on the client, on the tunnel interface), that the packets are received by the server (tcpdump on server, on the tunnel interface), and that the packets are correctly sent out the breakout interface (tcpdump on the server on the breakout interface). And probably you should upload these files to somewhere we can download them from.

Comment: wow. seems not easy. Please confirm my next actions:
1) I do TCPdump on the client(windows) side on TAP interface?(I tried it to do, but it doesn't work)---------2) I did the TCPdump on server side, and u saw the outcome. 3) How I can detect this interface which server use to breakout to net? What it's name? And another thing, you wanna me to write some sort of log. How I can make this again? On my VPS I use Debian 8.(TUN) on My client side Windows 7(TAP). Big thanks!

Comment: And I would like to mention. I want to use the VPN to tunnel my internet connection from client to internet through VPN. Just to make it clear

Comment: Hey buddy, can you please answer? I am still waiting for you!